# Creating Distinct Sums

Tags: code-golf, number

You should write a program or function which receives an integers as input and outputs or returns two integers whose sum is the first one.

There is one further requirement: **no number can be part of the output for two different inputs**.

### Details

- You should be able to handle inputs for at least the range `-32768 .. 32767` (inclusive).
- If your datatype can't handle arbitrary whole numbers, that is fine but your algorithm should work for arbitrary large and small numbers in theory.

### Examples

Each block shows a part of a correct or incorrect solution in the format of `input => output`.

```
1 => 6 -5
2 => -2 4
15 => 20 -5

Incorrect, as `-5` is used in two outputs.
```

```
-5 => -15 10
0 => 0 0
1 => 5 6
2 => -5 7

Incorrect, as `5 + 6` isn't `1`.
```

```
-1 => -1 0
0 => 6 -6
2 => 1 1

Can be correct if other outputs doesn't collide.
```

This is code golf so the shortest entry wins.

Comment: Can you restrict the input range to -32768 .. 32767 so we don't have to use 17 bit integers?

Comment: @FUZxxl My bad, that was the intention. Fixed.

Comment: Can the output be a list/array/tuple/set/etc containing two integers? (  For example, f(1) => [2, -1]  )

Comment: There seem to be several solutions which fundamentally rely on a restricted integer size--for example, by multiplying the input by a large positive and a large negative number.  It seems to me that such solutions are failing the requirement that "your algorithm should work for arbitrary large and small numbers in theory".  Am I misreading the question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Pyth, 8 bytes

```
_J^Q3+QJ
```

[Demonstration.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=_J%5EQ3%2BQJ&input=2&debug=1) Equivalent to the Python 2 code:

```python
Q=input()
J=Q**3
print -J
print Q+J
```

So, the output has form `(-n**3, n+n**3)`

Some outputs:

```
-5 (125, -130)
-4 (64, -68)
-3 (27, -30)
-2 (8, -10)
-1 (1, -2)
 0 (0, 0)
 1 (-1, 2)
 2 (-8, 10)
 3 (-27, 30)
 4 (-64, 68)
 5 (-125, 130)
```

These are distinct because cubes are far enough spaced that adding `n` to `n**3` is not enough to cross the gap to the next cube :`n**3 < n+n**3 < (n+1)**3` for positive `n`, and symmetrically for negative `n`.

Comment: You don't need the `,` at the beginning, two lines appears to be allowed.

Comment: @Maltysen I tried removing it, but only the second number prints. Maybe the `J` assignment suppresses printing?

Comment: Oh yeah you're right, sorry.

Comment: `-` in pyth is not the unary negation operator, its `_`, so `_J^Q3+QJ` works as expected.

Comment: @Maltysen Actually, that works, I just need the `J` to not be on the outside.  Thanks for poking me about this.

Answer (score 8):

## [Snowman 0.1.0](https://github.com/KeyboardFire/snowman-lang/releases/tag/v0.1.0-alpha), 101 chars

```
}vg0aa@@*45,eQ.:?}0AaG0`NdE`;:?}1;bI%10sB%nM2np`*`%.*#NaBna!*+#@~%@0nG\]:.;:;bI~0-NdEnMtSsP" "sP.tSsP
```

Input on STDIN, space-separated output on STDOUT.

This uses the same method as isaacg's answer.

Commented version with newlines, for "readability":

```
}vg0aa          // get input, take the first char
@@*45,eQ.       // check if it's a 45 (ASCII for -) (we also discard the 0 here)
// this is an if-else
:               // (if)
  ?}0AaG        // remove first char of input (the negative sign)
  0`NdE`        // store a -1 in variable e, set active vars to beg
;
:               // (else)
  ?}1           // store a 1 in variable e, set active vars to beg
;bI             // active variables are now guaranteed to be beg
%10sB           // parse input as number (from-base with base 10)
%nM             // multiply by either 1 or -1, as stored in var e earlier
2np`*`          // raise to the power of 2 (and discard the 2)
%.              // now we have the original number in b, its square in d, and
                //   active vars are bdg
*#NaBna!*+#     // add abs(input number) to the square (without modifying the
                //   input variable, by juggling around permavars)
@~%@0nG\]       // active vars are now abcfh, and we have (0>n) in c (where n is
                //   the input number)
:.;:;bI         // if n is negative, swap d (n^2) and g (n^2+n)
~0-NdEnM        // multiply d by -1 (d is n^2 if n is positive, n^2+n otherwise)
tSsP            // print d
" "sP           // print a space
.tSsP           // print g
```

Commentary on the very first Snowman solution on PPCG: I think my design goal of making my language as confusing as possible has been achieved.

This actually could have been a lot shorter, but I'm an idiot and forgot to implement negative numbers for string -> number parsing. So I had to manually check whether there was a `-` as the first character and remove it if so.

Comment: Way better than Brainfuck.

Comment: How does Ostrich feel about this? ;)

Answer (score 6):

## Pyth, <s>15</s> 11 bytes

*4 bytes thanks to @Jakube*

```
*RQ,hJ.aQ_J
```

[Demonstration.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=*RQ%2ChJ.aQ_J&input=6&debug=0)

This maps as follows:

```
0  -> 0, 0
1  -> 2, -1
-1 -> -2, 1
2  -> 6, -4
-2 -> -6, 4
```

And so, on, always involving `n^2` and `n^2 + n`, plus or minus.

Answer (score 5):

## APL, 15 bytes

```
{(-⍵*3)(⍵+⍵*3)}
```

This creates an unnamed monadic function that returns the pair -n^3 (`-⍵*3`), n+n^3 (`⍵+⍵*3`).

You can [try it online](http://tryapl.org/?a=%7B%28-%u2375*3%29%28%u2375+%u2375*3%29%7D%A8%u23735&run).

Answer (score 2):

## [O](https://github.com/phase/o), <s>17 15</s> 9 bytes

Uses some new features of O.

```
Q3^.Q+p_p
```

**Older Version**

```
[i#.Z3^*\Z3^)_*]o
```

Comment: I'm starting to enjoy these O answers, though I would like it more if the interpreter wasn't written in Java... ;)

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos It's not as small as Pyth, but it can beat CJam & GolfScript in some instances. It defiantly can beat anything having to do with arrays, as they're so powerful.

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth - <strike>11</strike> 10 bytes

Just multiplies by <strike>10e10 and -10e10+1</strike> Thanks to @xnor for showing me that I could use `CG` for the number.

```
*CGQ_*tCGQ
```

[Try it online here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=*CGQ_*tCGQ&input=15&debug=0).

Comment: You can make a suitably huge number as `CG`.

Comment: @xnor adding to tips list.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, <s>29</s> 27

### Edit: doesn't meet the requirement in the 2nd "Details" bullet point

*Bonus: it works from -99998 to 99998 inclusive*

---

```
lambda n:[99999*n,-99998*n]
```

This creates an anonymous function*, which you can use by enclosing in brackets and then placing the argument in brackets afterwards like this:

```
(lambda n:[99999*n,-99998*n])(arg)
```

*Thanks to @vioz- for suggesting this.

---

Example input / output:

```
>>> (lambda n:[99999*n,-99998*n])(1)
[99999, -99998]
>>> (lambda n:[99999*n,-99998*n])(2)
[199998, -199996]
>>> (lambda n:[99999*n,-99998*n])(0)
[0, 0]
>>> (lambda n:[99999*n,-99998*n])(-1)
[-99999, 99998]
>>> (lambda n:[99999*n,-99998*n])(-2)
[-199998, 199996]
>>> (lambda n:[99999*n,-99998*n])(65536)
[6553534464, -6553468928]
```

Comment: Nice post! Just so you know, you can remove the `f=` and leave it as an anonymous function, which is still a valid answer. Then you can take down your byte count to 27 :)

Comment: "...your algorithm should work for arbitrary large and small numbers in theory."  Obviously `(lambda n:[99999*n,-99998*n])(99999)` and `(lambda n:[99999*n,-99998*n])(-99998)` will collide in theory (and in practice).

Comment: @mathmandan You're right, I'll edit my post to make it clear that it doesn't meet the requirements. I would try to write & test new code but I'm on mobile away from my computer.

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell, 16 bytes

I shamelessly copied @xnor's method. There probably isn't much better than this.

```
f x=(-x^3,x^3+x)
```